# Thoughts on a simple way of versioning several Database tables in code

Tags: database, versioning

I want to create a simple versioning system and I was wondering about some simple yet elegant design patterns.

Since these tables are being used by lots of code so I need to leave them intact or all the existing queries will break. I was thinking:

```
-Duplicate the schema for existing tables but append Versioning to the names and a version col
-Deploy a script to copy all existing data into the Version tables as version 1.0
-Allow users to save as a new version or rollback to a previous one
-If they choose to rollback to an existing one I just update the original Tables data from the versioning tables for that version 
-If they choose to save a new version, I create new records in the Version tables and update the original afterwards
```

I know this is not an efficient way so anyone have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database supports updatedable views then you can:

- add versioning columns to the existing tables
- rename the existing tables by appending some suffix to them (e.g. _NONVER)
- create updatable views for every table with the original table names that will return all the columns expect the newly added versioning columns